# Recursive Partial application until type/result desired

Tags: scala

Is there any way to write a function(lst: List(T), fun: ) that iterates through lst and partially applies each element to fun and returning a new function each time and recursively doing this until the result of the function application is :Future[T] as desired and not a function type?

`fun` is a curried function

Something like this.

```
def partialAppRec(lst : List[T], fun: ?) =
//pardon the non-exhaustive pattern match
  lst match {
  case x::xs =>
    val test = fun(x)
    if (test: Future[T]) return test
    partialAppRec(xs, (fun(x) _) )
}
```

But what type would fun be? Is there anyway to say that fun: , disregarding parameters that it could take. I want to be able to take in a `fun` of variable parameters but that returns `Future[T]`. `f : ..=>Future[T]` but I'm not sure something like this exists.

Any tips/suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to apply your fun to elements of `List[T]`, then the only parameter that function can take is `T`. 
Also, don't use `return` in scala, it is (almost) always a wrong thing to do.

Comment: Not exactly what I want to do. That would just be lst.map(...). It's more of using the lst representing the args of fun and wanting to do fun(elt1,elt2, ..., elt n)

Comment: I'd first think about the type of `fun`, then the problem will be much easier. I think you want `fun` to return an ADT, or just a regular `Option[Future[T]]`.

Answer (score 1):

How about `Either`?

```
 trait Fun[T] extends Function[T, Either[Fun[T], Future[T]]]
 object Fun {
   def apply[T](f: T => Either[Fun[T], Future[T]]) = 
     new Fun[T] { def apply(t: T) = f(t) }
}

 def partialAppRec[T](lst: List[T], fun: Fun[T]): Future[T] = lst match {
   case Nil => ???
   case head :: tail => fun(head) match {
     case Right(fu) => fu
     case Left(f) => partialAppRec(tail, f)
   }
 }
```

Comment: This looks like it could work but it doesn't seem to typecheck atm. Something about `application does not take parameters` - not recognizing fun correctly. in `case head::tail => fun(head) match {`

Comment: @Jay I fixed a couple of typos, should compile now.